# Process out of memory error using nodejs when nothing should be that large

Tags: javascript, node.js, out-of-memory

The exact error says "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory" The program should get the prime number in the nth position but fails no matter how small the number is. What exactly does this error mean and how do I fix it?

```
var primes = [2, 3, 5];
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 6;
var nthPrime = function(number){
    while (primes.length <= number){
        y = 0;
        while (y <= primes.length){
            x = primes[y];
            if (z % x === 0){
                y++;
            } else{
                primes.push(z);
                z++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(primes[number]);
};
nthPrime(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second while loop is an infinite loop. The `else` statement is happening more frequently than the `if` statement, after the first two iterations. This means the `primes` array is increasing in length faster than the `y` value. Work out the logic some more and this particular error should work itself out.